# Jquery ajax promise returning undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, promise

My second ajax call always returning undefined.

```
var getrpmData = fetchAjaxData(
                {
                    "MachineID": MachineID,
                    "diaVal": diaVal,
                    "ggVal": ggVal,
                    "ITEMID": ITEMID
                },
                "url_to_call");


            getrpmData.then((rpmData) => {
                console.log(rpmData.d);//getting desired value from this
                if (rpmData.d) {
                    shifHourUsigRPM(rpmData.d);
                }
            })
                .then((prodRate) => {

                    console.log(prodRate.d.KnittingQty);//not getting value
                })
                .fail((err) => {
                    console.log(err);
                }
                );


// Generic function to make an AJAX call
var fetchAjaxData = function (dataParam, dataURL) {
// Return the $.ajax promise
return $.ajax({
    beforeSend: function () { $.blockUI(); },
    complete: function () { $.unblockUI(); },
    type: "POST",
    url: dataURL,
    dataType: "JSON",
    contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
    data: JSON.stringify(dataParam)
});
}

function shifHourUsigRPM(rpm) {

var KnittingWorkOrderId = GetValue($("#cmbKWO").val(), 'dlKWO');
var ITEMID = $("#cmbFabName").val();
var machineId = GetValue($("#cmbMachineID").val(), 'dlMachineID');

    //fetchAjaxData(
    //    { "this_RPM": rpm, "fab": ITEMID, "machineId": machineId, "KWOID": KnittingWorkOrderId },
    //    "pageKnittingProductionPlanning_MachineWise.aspx/KPP_Load_QtyByRPM");   
   return $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       beforeSend: function () { $.blockUI(); },
       complete: function () { $.unblockUI(); },
        url: "pageKnittingProductionPlanning_MachineWise.aspx/KPP_Load_QtyByRPM",
        dataType: "JSON",
        contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
        data: JSON.stringify({ "this_RPM": rpm, "fab": ITEMID, "machineId": machineId, "KWOID": KnittingWorkOrderId }),
        success: function (data) {
           //var result = data.d;
       }
   });
```

my back end web service is working fine, and returning desired value but not getting that value on second `console.log` call

getting below response from network response:

```
{"d":{"__type":"BLL.Kniting_BLL.KnittingQty","TotalFabNeed":"5 is production rate","RemFabQty":null}}
```

I'm expecting my second `console.log` should print

> "5 is production rate"

, but getting `undefined` printed on console

Comment: Your first `then` callback is not returning a value. Whatever you expect as value for the second `then`'s callback argument, it will be what you return in the first `then` callback. As you don't return anything there, you don't get anything in the second.

Comment: my first then is calling **shifHourUsigRPM(rpmData.d);** which should return another promise

Comment: So add `return` before the call to `shifHourUsigRPM(rpmData.d)`. Otherwise that returned promise is going nowhere.

Comment: please have a look at shifHourUsigRPM(rpmData.d) implementation which I have included below my code. shifHourUsigRPM is returning for sure

Comment: I am not talking about that function's internal return statement. That is OK. I am talking about what you do with the returned promise: you don't do anything with it. You need to return it (again) from within the `then` callback. Just put a `return` before the *call* of `shifHourUsigRPM(rpmData.d)`.

Comment: @trincot you are right.  putting a return before the call of shifHourUsigRPM(rpmData.d) worked just fine. 
Please consider putting this comment as an answer, so that I can accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first `then` callback is not returning a value, so the second `then` callback
will get `undefined` as argument.

You should *return* the value that `shifHourUsigRPM(rpmData.d)` returns (i.e. a promise), so add `return` before that call.

```
getrpmData.then((rpmData) => {
    if (rpmData.d) {
        return shifHourUsigRPM(rpmData.d);
//      ^^^^^^
    }
})
```